# Removing Windows Domain name from FQDN

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, dns-zone

I hope someone can help with this, it feels like a stupid question but I'm trying to learn in a semi-live environment and I've had trouble finding an answer to this. I'm trying to be specific, so I hope this doesn't just immediately get closed for a reason I don't understand.

I have a Windows 2012 domain. It seemed simple to me to call the domain fishkake.com (not my real  FQDN) but I've seen other posts here that say I shouldn't do that. So my domain is called angel.fishkake.com. And I use NETBIOS and UPN as per another SF post so that users should never see the word angel.

In tutorials for DNS (example: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324260/how-to-configure-dns-records-for-your-web-site-in-windows-server-2003), I've seen how to add a CNAME for www but this is based on a zone called domain.com. My zone is called angel.fishkake.com but I want a CNAME for www.fishkake.com - NOT www.angel.fishkake.com.

The actual problem which started me down this track was that I have a mail server running on platypus.angel.fishkake.com which I want to install a SSL certificate on.

So the question is, how do I remove angel?

Do I need to create a new zone called fishkake.com that mirrors angel.fishkake.com?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to change a Windows AD domain once it's set up, but you actually should be using a sub domain, e.g. `ad.example.com`, so you have the basics correct. If you had used `example.com` as an AD domain directly, you would have the problem of maintaining two different set of name servers for the same domain: internally and externally.

Now, you simply delegate control of your `ad.example.com` subdomain to your domain controllers and let the external name servers for `example.com` handle your `www.example.com`. Or, if you really wish to have separate records internally, you may add another zone for `example.com` on your internal name servers.

Comment: To be clear for anyone else who finds this, and to open myself up to corrections if I misunderstood... I created a new primary zone on my DNS on the DC called example.com and manually added my servers in to it. Now I can look up server1.domain.com as well as server1.angel.domain,com - this is internal of course, external DNS is a totally different matter about which I currently know nothing. Thanks Esa!